# Openerp wizard treeview no action buttons

Tags: python, xml, openerp-7

I have made a button(type=object) which calls this method:

```
def get_work(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return {
        'name': 'Purchase Wizard',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'mrp.bom.work',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'context': {'bom_workcenter_id': ids[0]},
        'domain':[('bom_workcenter_id','=',ids[0])],
    }
```

and it works ok, but I can't add any button nor do I have a button to create.

What I get:
http://i58.tinypic.com/r1h5p3.png

What I want:
http://i62.tinypic.com/21981s4.png

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default it shows the create buttons unless you don't have permission to do so.

Check your tree view if create does not set create='false'.

Or just force it by adding attribute ***'create':True,*** to your method return.